# Create a registry key and have it add the time/date/year of the computer?

Tags: windows-registry

I want to add a registry key:
"HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Note****pany\Components" /v OOBE_Version /t REG_SZ /d "01 Jun 22 12:00" /f

This is what I have now but I have to manually change the time.
Is there anyway I can change the time to have it pull what the computer time/date is.

Comment: I don't really understand the question.  I am thinking that you are running this command from a prompt? .. using reg.exe ?? .. we need to know a heck of a lot more than what you provided to answer your question.  Please elaborate on what you are doing and the environment you are using.

Comment: What would be the point of getting a **fixed** value from the Registry. if you want the **continually changing** date and time? You could just type `echo %date% %time%` in CMD, or format the date-time as you wish: https://ss64.com/nt/time.html .

Comment: It is a registry key we set, and the date/month/year is manually put in.  Can I put something else that will pull the date/month/year in there, so we don't have to set it manually.   No it is not via command prompt, it needs to be set via registry key

Comment: @SuziePiper - You can easily write an application that will set a registry key.  As other have indicate your question is confuisng.

Comment: Where the date is specified in the registry key:  "01 Jun 22 12:00".    We have to change each it each month to reflect our image. 

I want that part to be dynamic each month, and pull the month/year and insert in that registry key.  
Does this make a little more sense.

Comment: PowerShell can determine the current time and print it into a specified format you can then use the same script to write the value to a key.  We are not a script writing service.